# Ubuntu 16.10: Certain USB-Ports Disconnecting

Tags: usb, firefox, video, usb-drive, 16.10

Using Ubuntu 16.10 Gnome. This issue always occurs when playing YouTube-Videos on Mozilla Firefox. Sometimes it also happens randomly when closing windows.

The CPU usage does not go over 30% when a video is played.
The RAM usage is 1.2GB/8GB
The Swap usage is at 0GB/4GB

After the disconnect of my wireless mouse and my USB-Headset, this is shown in the Kernel-Log:

```
Oct 28 15:04:44 CubeDesktop gnome-terminal-[1668]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55ae75ce47b0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop kernel: [  109.131952] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HcDoneHead not written back; disabled
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop kernel: [  109.131960] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HC died; cleaning up
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop kernel: [  109.132025] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop kernel: [  109.183639] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop fwupd[1545]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 28 15:05:24 CubeDesktop fwupd[1545]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 28 15:05:27 CubeDesktop gnome-software[1489]: failed to get updates: no results to show
```

2x USB2 Ports become unusable and disconnect. All other ports still work.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? How many USB devices are you using? What kind of devices? is it the same 2 ports that stop working, or is it random?

Comment: @TheXed Same ports and it's a desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar problem (in my case with a usb sound card which would disconnect after working for a few seconds, bricking the port to which it was connected) by installing a more up-to-date kernel:

4.9.0-040900rc3-generic

I simply downloaded the .deb file for my architecture from,
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
and installed it with the software updater.

After rebooting, the usb device was back to its normal behavior.